# TypeError: cannot subtract DatetimeArray from ndarray while trying to get years column

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm trying to create new column with this code:

```
df['Collected'] = '2014-12-07'
df['Collected'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Collected'], format='%Y', errors='ignore')
df['Days_is_client'] = df['Collected'] - df['Year_Birth']
```

And here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_38/2291006566.py in <module>
      7 df['Collected'] = '2014-12-07'
      8 df['Collected'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Collected'], format='%Y', errors='ignore')
----> 9 df['Days_is_client'] = df['Collected'] - df['Year_Birth']
     10 df.drop('Collected', axis=1, inplace=True)
TypeError: cannot subtract DatetimeArray from ndarray
```

Comment: Hi, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335143/11246056